# Add pickle to a Python extension written in C++

Tags: c++, python, c, pickle

I have written a Python extension in C. It works, no issues. Now I'd want to use pickle with it. From the documentation I'm confused. I wrote a test `__reduce__` function as suggested here for "extensions":

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#the-pickle-protocol

what I miss is what the "callable object" should be. I have tried with the result from `PyObject_Type(self)`. This is "callable" and essentially works, but when the object is unickled it calls the `__init__` and this gives me some trouble.

Is there any standard way to have a callable that calls the just the `__new__` method, avoiding the class initialization?

Comment: In principle, `__init__` should not be called, and that's pickle's preferred way. See under `__getinitargs__`: "When a pickled class instance is unpickled, its `__init__()` method is normally *not* invoked". Are you implementing `__getinitargs__`?

Comment: Ok, forget about it. That's only for normal classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `__new__` and you're using type as your metaclass, `__init__` will be called if the result of `__new__` is a subtype of your type.  Put another way,  Let's say you have a class Foo.  If you call the result of `PyObject_Type(self)`, that is the same as calling `Foo()`.  This means that Foo.`__new__` will be called and if the return value is a subtype of Foo, `__init__` will be called.

Digging a bit deeper, when you call Foo(), that's really calling type_call (in typeobject.c), this is what does the tp_new followed by tp_init.  If you directly provide your object's new function (e.g. Foo_new() instead of PyObject_Type(self)), then you're calling `__new__` without calling `__init__` and you can get what you're looking for.  (Don't forget to provide Foo as an argument for `__new__`).

So, to finally answer your question, you can simply call `Foo.__new__(Foo, ...)`.  Here's some code that does what you're looking for.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print "__init__"

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (Foo.__new__, (Foo, ))

print "one"
x = Foo()              # prints __init__

print "two"
y = Foo.__new__(Foo)   # does not print __init__

print "three"
import pickle
p = pickle.dumps(Foo)
z = pickle.loads(p)    # does not print __init__
```

As an aside, when I was trying to figure this all out, I found that in almost all cases, I could, in fact, implement my code and allow `__init__` to be called.  My error stemmed from the fact that I was not separating out the stuff that goes into the third argument of the `__reduce__` tuple.  It's perfectly OK to provide nothing for the second argument (provided that `__init__` accepts that) and just provide a bunch of stuff in the 3rd argument that will update `__dict__` directly.  If you look through the cpython source code in the Modules and Objects directory, you'll see a number of implementations of `__reduce__` all of which work this way.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you but for some reason what you described in Python was not happening in the type define by my compiled C++ extension.

In particular the first item in the `__reduce__` output was:
`PyTuple_SetItem(res,0,PyObject_Type(self));`
as a said this will result in _pickle.loads(...)_, or similar, to call the object itself and indeed go trough `__new__` and `__init__`.

I have found a simple solution just forcing Pickle to use the protocol 2. This doesn't need to implement a `__reduce__` function but needs `__getnewargs__` and the usual `__setstate__` and `__getstate__`.

Comment: right, instead of returning `PyObject_Type(self)`, you'd want to use self->tp_new, did you try that?  Let me know if that does or does not work.  If it does, I'll update my post.  If it does not, I'll go figure out what I wrote incorrectly.